# Expected revenue for overbooked hotel.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> A hotel has 120 rooms that can be booked for 60€ a night. Typically, 3% of the guests do not show
> up to their booking. In this case, the hotel still gets 20€. Assume the hotel is fully booked. a)
> Calculate the expected revenue. b) The hotel now allows 122 bookings for its 120 rooms. Every
> guest that does not get a room, costs the hotel 60€. What is the expected revenue now?

My idea for a) was to try and calculate the expected number of visitors. Let $X$ be a random variable that denotes the number of guests that show up to their booking. Since $X \sim \text{Bin}(120, 0.97)$ then $E[X]= np = 120\cdot0.97 =116.4$, so the expected revenue is $116.4\cdot60 + 3.6\cdot20 = 7056$

I don't really know how to approach b) though. Any tips?

Comment: Same as before, only now you need to separate out a couple cases.  If nobody shows up, if only one person is a no-show, and all the rest.  Note:  you might find it computationally simpler to model the no-show via a Poisson process.  The answers shouldn't be terribly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be pedantic, but if I understand, the problems is asking for profits, rather than revenue.

For (a), you are correct but I will reprint here for completeness. Let $X \sim Bin(120, 0.97)$ denote how many guests will show up and $R_a$ denote your revenue from $120$ bookings. Your cost in this part is $0$. Then $120 - X$ represents the number of guests that do not show up. Thus

$$
E(R) = 60 E(X) + 20 E(120 - X) = 60(120)(0.97) + 20(120) - 20(120)(0.97) = 7056.
$$

Similarly, for (b), let $Y \sim Bin(122, 0.97)$ denote the number of guests that show up and let $R$ denote your revenue from $122$ bookings and $C$ denote your costs from not having enough rooms. An easy way to think of this is using total expectation. For brevity, let $p = P(Y = 121) = 122(0.97)^{121}(0.03)$ and $q = P(Y = 122) = (0.97)^{122}$, which are just numbers you can put in your calculator.

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
E(R - C) &= E(R - C | Y \leq 120) P(Y \leq 120) + E(R - C | Y > 120) P(Y > 120) \\ \\
&= 7056(1 - p - q) + (7056 - 60 E(Y - 120| Y > 120)) (p + q) \\ \\
&= 7056 - 60(p + 2q)(p + q)
\end{align*}
$$

Of course if $Y \leq 120$ then it is the same as part (a), hence it is just $7056$. If $Y > 120$, then it's $7056$ for the full hotel, but $-60$ for each additional guest.